# Getting Null values using WindowSpec in spark/java

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a dataframe :

```
+----------+------------+------------+--------------------+
|   acc    |id_Vehicule |id_Device   |dateTracking        | 
+----------+------------+------------+--------------------+
|  1       |  1         |  2         |2020-02-12 14:50:00 |            
|  0       |  1         |  2         |2020-02-12 14:59:00 | 
|  0       |  2         |  3         |2020-02-12 15:10:00 |
|  1       |  2         |  3         |2020-02-12 15:20:00 |
+----------+------------+------------+--------------------+
```

I want to get in output :

```
 +----------+------------+------------+--------------------+----------------+
|   acc    |id_Vehicule |id_Device   |dateTracking        |  acc_previous  |
+----------+------------+------------+--------------------+----------------+
|  1       |  1         |  2         |2020-02-12 14:50:00 | null           |                
|  0       |  1         |  2         |2020-02-12 14:59:00 |  1             |
|  0       |  2         |  3         |2020-02-12 15:10:00 |  null          |
|  1       |  2         |  3         |2020-02-12 15:20:00 |  0             |
+----------+------------+------------+--------------------+----------------+
```

I tried  the following code :

```
WindowSpec w =org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window.partitionBy("idVehicule","idDevice","dateTracking").orderBy("dateTracking");
    Dataset <Row> df= df1.withColumn("acc_previous",lag("acc",1).over(w));
    df.show();
```

I get on result ;

```
 +----------+------------+------------+--------------------+----------------+
|   acc    |id_Vehicule |id_Device   |dateTracking        |  acc_previous  |
+----------+------------+------------+--------------------+----------------+
|  1       |  1         |  2         |2020-02-12 14:50:00 | null           |                
|  0       |  1         |  2         |2020-02-12 14:59:00 | null           |
|  0       |  2         |  3         |2020-02-12 15:10:00 | null           |
|  1       |  2         |  3         |2020-02-12 15:20:00 | null           |
+----------+------------+------------+--------------------+----------------+
```

If you have any idea 
I will be very grateful

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, maybe it will help another person.
The problem was because of the "dateTracking" column it should not be like a partitioning column, so I removed it.

```
WindowSpec w =org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window.partitionBy("idVehicule","idDevice").orderBy("dateTracking");
Dataset <Row> df= df1.withColumn("acc_previous",lag("acc",1).over(w));
df.show();
```